# How do I concatenate two arrays and store to one string in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

any one can help me. i want output:a-1,b-2,c-3.
this is my code below any. where can i change the logic

```
        string x="a,b,c";
        string y="1,2,3";
        string z=string.Empty;

        string[] q=x.Split(',');
        string[] w=y.Split(',');

       for(int i=0; i<q.Length;i++)
       {  
       for(int j=0; j<w.Length;j+=1) 
       {
          z += q[i] +"-"+ w[j] +",";                   
       }
       }
       Console.WriteLine(z);
```

Comment: Why are you using two loops? If you want to iterate over both arrays in parallel, use i for both.

Answer (score 0):

use zip

```
      string x="a,b,c";
        string y="1,2,3";
        string z=string.Empty;

        string[] q=x.Split(',');
        string[] w=y.Split(',');

       var res = q.Zip(w, (a,b)=>a + "-" + b);
       Console.WriteLine(res);
```